# Resources for SQL Server programming?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tutorial

I have tried to search from the web resources for SQL Server programming. Basically I'm trying to search good tutorial for programming SQL Server (creating procedures, triggers, cursors etc.). Can you give some helping hand and show some links for good tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/default.aspx as there's a wealth of info on there. Also, for specific syntax/queries I find Pinal Dave's blog to be essential: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/

Comment: yes msdn is a wealth of info for SQL Statments(TSQL) and more.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sql-server-performance.com is a great place to start.